# Facing issue testing akka http cache

Tags: scala, caching, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP cache to cache my result. But i am facing issue to test it.

```
class GoogleAnalyticsController @Inject()(cache: Cache[String, HttpResponse],
                                          googleAnalyticsApi: GoogleAnalyticsTrait,
                                          googleAnalyticsHelper: GoogleAnalyticsHelper)
                                         (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer) {


def routes: Route =

      post {
        pathPrefix("pageviews") {
          path("clients" / Segment) { accountsClientId =>
            entity(as[GoogleAnalyticsMetricsRequest]) { googleAnalyticsMetricsRequest =>
         val googleAnalyticsMetricsKey = "key"
         complete(
           cache.getOrLoad(googleAnalyticsMetricsKey, _ => getGoogleAnalyticsMetricsData(accountsClientId, googleAnalyticsMetricsRequest))
          ) 
         }

       }
     }
   }

 private def getGoogleAnalyticsMetricsData(accountsClientId: String,
                                            request: GoogleAnalyticsMetricsRequest) = {
    val payload = generate(request)
    val response = googleAnalyticsApi.googleAnalyticsMetricResponseHandler(accountsClientId, payload) // response from another microservice
googleAnalyticsHelper.googleAnalyticsMetricResponseHandler(
       googleAnalyticsMetricsRequest.metricName, response)
}

}

class GoogleAnalyticsHelper extends LoggingHelper {

  def googleAnalyticsMetricResponseHandler(metricName: String, response: Either[Throwable, Long]): Future[HttpResponse] =
    response.fold({ error =>
      logger.error(s"An exception has occurred while getting $metricName from behavior service and error is ${error.getMessage}")
      Marshal(FailureResponse(error.getMessage)).to[HttpResponse].map(httpResponse => httpResponse.copy(status = StatusCodes.InternalServerError))
    }, value =>
      Marshal(MetricResponse(metricName, value)).to[HttpResponse].map(httpResponse => httpResponse.copy(status = StatusCodes.OK))
    )

}
```

Test case: Sharing only the relevant part

```
"get success metric response for " + pageviews + " metric of given accounts client id" in { fixture =>
      import fixture._

      val metricResponse = MetricResponse(pageviews, 1)
      val eventualHttpResponse = Marshal(metricResponse).to[HttpResponse].map(httpResponse => httpResponse.copy(status = StatusCodes.OK))

      when(cache.getOrLoad(anyString, any[String => Future[HttpResponse]].apply)).thenReturn(eventualHttpResponse)
      when(googleAnalyticsApi.getDataFromGoogleAnalytics(accountsClientId, generate(GoogleAnalyticsRequest(startDate, endDate, pageviews))))
        .thenReturn(ApiResult[Long](Some("1"), None))
      when(googleAnalyticsHelper.googleAnalyticsMetricResponseHandler(pageviews, Right(1))).thenReturn(eventualHttpResponse)

      Post(s"/pageviews/clients/$accountsClientId").withEntity(requestEntity) ~>
        googleAnalyticsController.routes ~> check {
        status shouldEqual StatusCodes.OK
        responseAs[String] shouldEqual generate(metricResponse)
      }
    }
```

By doing this, I am best to test if the cache has the key but not able to test if cache misses the hit. In code coverage, it misses following highlighted part

> cache.getOrLoad(googleAnalyticsMetricsKey, **_ =>
>   getGoogleAnalyticsMetricsData(accountsClientId,
>   googleAnalyticsMetricsRequest)**)

If there is a design issue, please feel free to guide me on how can I make my design testable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way I see it this code has too much unrelated stuff. Can you create the same example with just the required bits. For example, I don't think all that route nesting and google analytics stuff is important in any way. If I am not misunderstanding it then all you want to keep is a simple route with a function to create the cache-key and another function to to actually get the value if not found on cache.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Okay, io can create a simple analogy for you. Thanks. Give some time.

Comment: It will also help you in actually locating the problematic parts.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I have updated question. Added all unknow pieces and avoided nesting of routes. Hope that will solve to know the issue

Comment: Can your just try with `any()` instead of whole `any[String => Future[HttpResponse]].apply` ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Tried now, but compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to mock the cache. You should create an actual object for cache instead of mocked one.

What you have done is, you have mocked the cache, in this case, the highlighted part will be not called as you are providing the mocked value. In the following stubbing, whenever `cache.getOrLoad` is found, `eventualHttpResponse` is returned:

`when(cache.getOrLoad(anyString, any[String => Future[HttpResponse]].apply)).thenReturn(eventualHttpResponse)`

and hence the function `getGoogleAnalyticsMetricsData(accountsClientId, googleAnalyticsMetricsRequest)` is never called.

Comment: Thanks and I will give it a shot.